# Can you help me use a "icon font" in search bar using CSS only to open the search bar?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have been trying to get a search icon to open up a search bar.  I am pretty close, but when you click on the search icon the search input doesn't open. When you click just to right of the icon it opens.  Is there a way to make this work **without** a background image? I want to be able to use icon fonts.

See it here: http://cdpn.io/mkAyi

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="searchbox" class="t-box2" type="text" value="Search" name="text">

<style>
    .t-box2 {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("../images/search_icon.png");
    background-position: 96% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #666666;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 21px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    padding: 2px 35px 2px 7px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1px;
}
.t-box2:hover {
     width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If u fiddle its easy fro every one to see the output. If u fiddle u will get more +1 by seeing ur answer

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I am try to get it done with a font-icon like font-awesome.  So when I edit the header area text I don't have to create a new image.